# How I can collect users’ tweets without typing their accounts

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, account, tweets

I would like to ask if there is a way to collect several tweets about different users, whether by Python or R, without specifying their account names?

Comment: What kind of tweet do you need ? Any type ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I sugest you to look the twitter API. Any kind of request can be done.
[Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api)

For instance :
import tweepy as tw

```
my_api_key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
my_api_secret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

auth = tw.OAuthHandler(my_api_key, my_api_secret)
api = tw.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)
    # get tweets from the API
    tweets = tw.Cursor(api.search,
                  q="#covid19",
                  lang="en",
                  since="2020-09-16").items(50)
    # store the API responses in a list
    tweets_copy = []
    for tweet in tweets:
        tweets_copy.append(tweet)
        
    print("Total Tweets fetched:", len(tweets_copy))
```

More detailed example could be found here : [Data science](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/get-data-from-twitter-api-in-python-step-by-step-guide/)

PS: You need to be more explicit next time. It's hard to help someone without any details.